# Moving a UIView on top of UITableView - touching the top UIView still selects table rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I have a UIView which contains three containers

```
Container A - contains a UITableView
Container B - contains Container C and Container O
Container C - contains a UITableView
* - touch event
@ - touch event

----------------------
|     |               |
| ---*|      B        |
| --- |               |
| -A- | -----------   |
| --- ||@----C---- |  |
|     | -----------   |
----------------------
```

An event happens where I shift the frame of Container B (and I show a view (labeled O) to the right of B, which isn't important). Now Container B is overlapping Container A

```
O - Other view (unimportant)
$ - original location of touch @

----------------------
|   |               | | 
| --|*     B        | |
| --|               | |
| -A|------------   |O|
| --||@-$--C----|   | |
|   |------------   | |
----------------------
```

But now, when I try to select a row in Container C's UITableView by touching the left edge of the row (@), the touch is being registered by Container A's UITableView. Or even if I touch on the view above the table (*), the corresponding row in A is selected.

I can solve part of the problem by changing the width of the Container A's UITableView. But then I still have the problem where if I touch table C (@), the C's row doesn't select. It's like it things the start of the table C is in the old location ($).

So what can I do so that tapping at the new @ location will select the correct row in C?

=======

**EDIT** with some code:

This is code I do in Container B. It's a very straight forward  animation of B's frame. self.view is Container B's UIView.

All the view's are on the screen (the "other" container is hidden) through the Storyboard. Other container is a subview of B.

```
// this code basically aligns the "other" container to the right/"offscreen" of 
// Container B. Yes extending beyond the frame of B, but this part works fine
CGRect otherContainerFrame = self.otherContainerView.frame;
otherContainerFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(self.view.frame);
[self.otherContainerView setFrame:otherContainerFrame];
[self.otherContainerView setHidden:NO];

// I'm going move Container B by the width of the "other" view
float offset = CGRectGetWidth(self.otherContainerView.frame);

CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.x -= offset;
[UIView animateWithDuration:.35
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view setFrame:frame];
                 }
];
```

Please let me know what other code you want to see.

Comment: Very good explanation, but I think we need to see the code you use to show and animate your containers to solve this issue...

Comment: @Beppe, I added code for the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I downloaded Reveal to visually see (in 3d) what was happening with the views. It looks like the diagrams I drew are not complete, and misleading.

Each of the containers A and B (which are UIViews) contain subviews A' and B' (also UIViews). In the animation block when I was changing self.view, I was really moving the frame for B'. The frame was moving out of the bounds of B.

```
----------------------
|  A' |      B'       |
| ---*|      B        |
| --- |               |
| -A- | -----------   |
| --- ||@----C---- |  |
|     | -----------   |
----------------------
```

So even the B' was overlapping A and A', I suppose in the hierarchy of views, the touch is still captured by the underlying subviews (containers) A and B. I don't fully think this is how it should happen, but I guess that's how things fall.

Anyway, the solution was simple.

instead of:

```
[self.view setFrame:frame];
```

I'm essentially going to do:

```
[self.view.superview setFrame:frame];
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... Not sure if this works in your case, but try to manage your animation in a bigger container that hold all your other container.

I mean, create a Container Z that contains A, B, O and their subviews and try to animate the position of B from Z, checking that B is in front of A.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I moved the logic to the parent ViewController of A and B, and the same behavior exists.